# Where to apply Schengen visa - EU citizen spouse but traveling to different EU country

Tags: visas, schengen

I am married to a EU citizen and we live abroad. If I apply through my husband's embassy, processing is easier, I am exempt of payment and I am guaranteed to receive the visa without hassle. I am planning a trip for a different EU country so I am wondering if it is really necessary for me to pay 60 euro and go through the extra paperwork and process that I would have to do to apply for my actual destination and port of entry. Opinions, suggestions?

Comment: Will you be travelling with your EU spouse, or on your own?

Answer (score 2):

Rules for Schengen visa, including those, actually apply to all countries in the area and not only to your husband's country of origin so the question is not so much where to apply but what's applicable to your situation.

If you fulfill the conditions (and in particular you are traveling together with your husband), you should (in principle) get a free visa quickly and with limited hassle from every Schengen country, not only your husband's country of origin.

If you don't, you might be able to apply for another (e.g. long-term) visa from your husband's country of origin and use that but, as far as I understand the rules, they should not give you a Schengen visa (since that country is not the destination, they should simply decline to process it).

If you are traveling alone without your husband and are not a resident in another EU country then I think you need a regular Schengen visa with all the fees and paperwork.